Running Cucumber in Deno
I am very happy with CucumberJS for running integration tests in my Typescript projects.
I now wanted to try Deno for easier and direct Typescript support. However I could not find a way of getting CucumberJS up and running in a Deno project. Has anyone here already succeeded in doing this?
I already tried starting it programmatically as explained in the documentation, however it is not loading the configuration file correctly and is apparently not able to use the Typescript implementations of my steps directly.

Almost a year down the line and v2 out, have you been able to get it to work?
